# How to calculate driving distance between two addresses using Google Maps API?

Tags: c#, api

I have a problem: I want to calculate driving distance between two points, but I don't want to use Google Maps. I just want to know the distance and save it into database, that it means I don't need Maps.
I know the latitude and longtutude of two points.
How shoud I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the "Crow Fly Distance", or, in other words, the straight line distance between 2 points you can use the Haversine formula.

Please refer to this link to know more about Haversine formula:
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want to calculate the driving distance.